# Calculate Width of a DIV based on sibling count (not-fixed) using CSS or LESS

Tags: javascript, html, css, d3.js, less

I have a parent DIV with widht 100%;

Now, on the fly, it is populated with n number of children DIVs.

Now, I want to be able to caclulate and assign their width in CSS or LESS using calc method only (flex display doesnt work in my actual code which does not actually just deals with DIV s but actually svg elements using d3) so that their width is in this pattern

width of n-th child DIV = (100% / n) - 10

How can i achieve that?

Also, the DIV s need to be of alternative colors which i have managed to figure out how?

Any ideas how can I assign width on the fly using css or less?

http://jsfiddle.net/7r029v9n/2/  - here is the Jsfiddle

here is my code so far

```
.parent {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50%;
    background: pink;
    border: 1px solid red;
    min-width: 400px;
    min-height: 200px;
}

.child {
    min-height: 200px;
    min-width: 10px;
    border: 1px solid black;   
    display: inline-block;
}

.child:nth-child(even) {
    background: blue; 
    width: calc(100%/n -10);
}

.child:nth-child(odd) {
    background: green;  
    width: calc(100%/n -10);
}
```

Comment: You might want to look into [CSS flexbox](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).

Comment: that flexbox link looks promising! I recently had this same problem and ended up resorting to tables... wish I would have seen that earlier!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Flexbox is perfect when you want to distribute the available space among children:

```css
#parent {
  display: flex;
}
.child {
  flex-grow: 1;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```js
var parent = document.getElementById('parent');
var child = document.createElement('div');
child.className = 'child';
var n = Math.round(Math.random() * 10);
for (var i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
  parent.appendChild(child.cloneNode(false));
}
```

```css
#parent {
  display: flex;
  min-width: 400px;
  min-height: 200px;
  background: pink;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
.child {
  min-height: 200px;
  min-width: 10px;
  border: 1px solid black;   
  display: inline-block;
  flex-grow: 1;
  margin: 5px;
}
.child:nth-child(even) {
  background: blue; 
}
.child:nth-child(odd) {
  background: green;  
}
```

```html
<div id="parent"></div>
```

You can also use CSS tables:

```css
#parent {
  display: table;
  table-layout: fixed;
  border-spacing: 10px;
  width: 100%;
}
.child {
  display: table-cell;
}
```

```js
var parent = document.getElementById('parent');
var child = document.createElement('div');
child.className = 'child';
var n = Math.round(Math.random() * 10);
for (var i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
  parent.appendChild(child.cloneNode(false));
}
```

```css
#parent {
  display: table;
  table-layout: fixed;
  border-spacing: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  min-width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  background: pink;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
.child {
  display: table-cell;
  height: 200px;
  width: 10px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.child:nth-child(even) {
  background: blue; 
}
.child:nth-child(odd) {
  background: green;  
}
```

```html
<div id="parent"></div>
```

Comment: That is a nice solution Oriol. however my actual code is a little more complex where flex is not going to work. In my actual code I am working with d3 library where i need to make stroke width of a line to be flexible enough to know how wide it needs to be. So, i need a solution where i need to set the width explicitly. If you can help, would be great. thank you very much for this answer though :)

Comment: @Ishita You could try using that flex code, and then if you need the width explicitly, get it using `getComputedStyle`

Answer (score 4):

AFAIK, the only way to know the count of siblings in current CSS is to use `:nth-child` and `:nth-last-child` in combination, e.g.

```
div:nth-child(1):nth-last-child(3),
div:nth-child(2):nth-last-child(2),
div:nth-child(3):nth-last-child(1) {
   width: 33.3%; /* if there are 3 divs, make them 1/3 of the container width */
}
```

But you will need to write such a selector for any count of the elements you decide to support, and every next selector will be longer than the previous.